# Angular 2: Scope of variable inside *ngFor

Tags: angular

Is it possible to get the *"items"* from **item-list** and transfer to **item-filter** and use it inside that component such as using a service?

```
<div class="container">
    <item-filter (testOut) = "retrieveMe($event)" ></item-filter>
    <div class="row">
    <item-list *ngFor = "let item of items | filter :   filterConditions" [storyInfo] = 'item'></item-list> 
    </div><!-- Row -->
</div><!-- Container-->
```

Comment: Please provide more details. What behavior you are expecting?

Comment: ok, i have the array and i am trying to filter it by using "filter" pipe. I would like to receive the output array after using pipe.

Comment: May be you can inject a service both in to 'item-filter' and 'item-list' components and using that service exchange 'item' between them.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not handling the filter logic in the root component and just pass the filtered item list to item-filter?

Comment: yeah, i was thinking the same. If i do that, i can probably filter the array inside the service.

Comment: My point is, why would you need a service and a pipe to do this? It seems at the most straight forward thing to do is to handle the filter in the parent component class and then pass the filtered list to *ngFor and item-filter.

Comment: @unitario, yeah there is, items is a array of objects and item here has the properties for each thumbnail(img, title, desc ..). So i can generate each thumbnail through ngFor.

Comment: @unitario, ok i get your point, but how i would be able to fire that? Because here *ngFor triggers itself for some reason that i don't know:) Which is perfect for me.

Comment: You should expect the same behavior if you filter the list in the component class and pass that to *ngFor. You just don't need to mess around with services.

Comment: I am just wondering, if created a function to filter the array in the component class, how can i trigger that function? or should i add that one in ngOnInit()?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141988/discussion-between-unitario-and-sahin-erbay).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the section from the pipe to the parent component, include a property for the filtered list and `@Input` that list into item-filter:

**Parent component class:**

```
items: any[] = [];
filteredItems: any[] = [];

retrieveMe(criteria: any): void {
  this.filteredItems = this.filter(items, criteria);
}

filter(items: any[], criteria: any): any[] {
  return // code from your pipe (input and output would be the same)
}
```

**Parent template:**

```
<div class="container">
  <item-filter (testOut)="retrieveMe($event)" [filteredItems]="filteredItems"></item-filter>
  <div class="row">
    <item-list *ngFor = "let item of filteredItems" [storyInfo] = 'item'></item-list> 
  </div><!-- Row -->
</div><!-- Container-->
```

**item-filter component class:**

```
import { ..., Input } from '@angular/core';

@Input() filteredItems: any[] // <- here's your filtered items list
```

Comment: i was right, retrieveMe function in the parent is not fired at all!

Comment: Then you have a problem with your @Output.

Comment: @Output works with the current system. I can transfer that from child to parent. No offense but it just doesn't make sense that *ngFor could trigger retrieveMe.

Comment: If you change filteredItems *ngFor will trigger. If it doesn't your code is wrong.

Comment: Yeah but, filteredItems  cannot be changed because retrieveMe function is not triggered in the first place.

Comment: Then I revert back to my third comment, your @Output its not properly implemented.

Comment: Ok, i will check that and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: It works perfect, but the problem now is that i don't have any items showing before making the filtering because filteredItem is empty. I tried to check that in ngOnInit and assign it to items but did't work. here is the code [link](https://jsfiddle.net/sahinerbay/n2o9m03a/)

Comment: this.items = this.filteredStories = this.filterService.getData()

Comment: thannks alot man!!! i have never seen or done that kind of statement before. Cool trick. Is there any down side of using it?

Comment: Not any drawbacks as far as I know of.